# VueJS router alias to particular param

Tags: vue-router, vuejs3

I have a lot of articles in my app, and the URL are written like this in Vue Router: `/article/:id`.

I have particular articles I want to "pin" and have easier URLs. For example: `/pinned-article`, which should point to `/article/3274` and `/other-pinned-article`, pointing to `/article/68173`.

I though about adding this to my routes, but it doesn't work:

```
{ path: '/article/3274', component: Article, alias: '/pinned-article' }
```

I thought about something else, involving another component:

```
{ path: '/pinned-article/:id', component: PinnedArticle }
```

The component `PinnedArticle` silently aliasing the correct article with a command like `router.alias` in the `<script>` section, but it apparently doesn't exist.

Is there a way to solve this problem? I thought I could use some answers I read here in Stackvoverflow (for examples when it comes to redirect `/me` to `/user/:id`, but it doesn't apply.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/redirect-and-alias.html#alias

https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/dev/examples/route-alias/app.js

Comment: I read the doc, if I ask here it's because I couldn't fins a way to do precisely what  I described ;)

Answer (score 3):

## addRoute

You can achieve this with [Dynamic Routing](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/dynamic-routing.html), which is not the same as dynamic route *matching*, i.e. route params.

<sup>(This solution works in both [Vue 3](https://next.router.vuejs.org/api/#addroute-2) and [Vue 2](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-addroute) with Vue Router >= 3.5.0)</sup>

By using the `addRoute` method of Vue router, you can create routes at runtime.  You can either use a `redirect` or not, depending on whether you want the url bar to read `/article/3274` or `/pinned`.

#### Redirect

If you want the url to change from `/pinned` to `/article/3274`, use `redirect`:

```js
methods: {
  pinRoute() {
    this.$router.addRoute({
      path: '/pinned',
      name: 'pinned',
      redirect: { name: 'article', params: { id: 3274 }}
    })
  }
}
```

Access the route like:

```js
this.$router.push('/pinned')
```

<sup>The above example assumes you give your Article route a `name: 'article'` property so you can redirect to it</sup>

#### Alias

You can keep the URL as `/pinned` using `alias`.  Normally the alias would go on the existing Article route definition, but that doesn't work well with route params.  You can use a "reverse alias" with a new route:

```js
methods: {
  pinRoute() {
    this.$router.addRoute({
      path: '/params/3274',
      name: 'pinned',
      alias: '/pinned',
      component: () => import('@/views/Article.vue')  // Article component path
    })
  }
}
```

Access the route like:

```js
this.$router.push('/pinned')
```

---

**Notes:**

- You'll probably want to pass an `id` argument to the `pinRoute` methods rather than hardcode them like in the examples above.
- A nice thing about `addRoute` with either method above is if the route already exists, say, from the last time you called the method, it gets overwritten.  So you can use the method as many times as you like to keep changing the destination of `/pinned`.  (The docs in both Vue 2 and Vue 3 say the route definition will get overwritten, though Vue 2 router throws a duplicate route warning.)
- Of course the pinned route won't automatically persist between app refreshes, so you'll need to save/load the pinned id (i.e. using `localStorage`, etc.) and run one of these methods on app load if you want that